# IndexError: list index out of range en bucle while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa para comparar el numero de multas de dos ciudades (ejercicio encontrado en la pagina de "HP codewars" de barcelona de 2016). Para ello, necesito que el dato sea una lista, pero cuando voy a finalizar la lista, me devuelve el error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

y si cambio el programa en varias partes, las operaciones estan mal resueltas. si sabéis ingles, os dejo por aquí el enunciado:

> The input is a set of records, ending with the # character.
>
> Each record of the speed cameras has 3 values:
>
> - The initial letter of the city name (W for Whynot or Z for Zzyzx)
> - The measured speed, expressed in mph (miles per hour)
> - The speed limit

```
W 60 75
Z 61 50
Z 64 38
W 54 75
Z 103 50
Z 47 55
#
```

y el programa en cuestión es este:

```
a=input()
w=0
z=0
if a!="#":
    b=[]
    for i in a:
        b.append(a.split())
        if (b[0])==(b[0]):
            if b[0]=="W" or "w":
                w=w+1
            else:
                z=z+1
        else:
            if b[0]=="Z" or "z":
                w=w+1
            else:
                z=z+1
    a=input()
print(str(w)+" fines to whynot")
print(str(z)+" fines to Zzyzx")
if w<z:
    print("Whynot inhabitants are safer at driving than Zzyzx ones")
elif w>z:
    print("Zzyzx inhabitants are safer at driving than Whynot ones")
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: el idioma del sitio es el castellano, por lo que sería recomendable que tradujeras el enunciado. Por otra parte, ¿dónde exactamente te da el error? Muestras bastantes líneas de código y cuesta mirarlas todas

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar traduzco el enunciado.

> `input` es un conjunto de registros, que termina con el caracter `#`.
>   Cada registro de las cámaras de velocidad (de tráfico, se entiende)
>   contiene 3 valores:
>
> - La inicial de la ciudad (W de Wyhnot ó Z de Zzyzx)
> - La velocidad que se registró en millas por hora (mph)
> - El límite de velocidad

De donde entiendo que se pide saber cuál de las 2 ciudades registró menos multas de tráfico.

Como *no sé de dónde viene* `input`, voy a suponer que es una lista de cadenas de texto, es decir,

```
input = ['W 60 75', 'Z 61 50', 'Z 64 38', 'W 54 75', 'Z 103 50', 'Z 47 55', '#']
```

Pero si no lo fuera bastaría con hacer

```
input = input.split('/n')
```

Y partir de aquí vuelvo a trocear cada una de las cadenas para que me quede una lista de listas.

```
datos = []
for valor in input:
    datos.append(valor.split())
```

Quedando:

```
datos = [['W', '60', '75'], ['Z', '61', '50'], ['Z', '64', '38'], ['W', '54', '75'], ['Z', '103', '50'], ['Z', '47', 55'], ['#']]
```

Una vez que he formateado los datos convenientemente, sólo falta sumar cuántas multas han recibido los habitantes de cada ciudad:

```
for lista in datos:
    if ((lista[0] == 'W') and (int(lista[1])>int(lista[2]))):
        w += 1 #que es equivalente a w=w+1
    elif ((lista[0] == 'Z') and (int(lista[1])>int(lista[2]))):
        z += 1
```

En conjunto queda:

```
w=0
z=0


input = input.split('/n')
datos = []

for valor in input:
    datos.append(valor.split())

for lista in datos:
    if ((lista[0] == 'W') and (int(lista[1])>int(lista[2]))):
        w += 1 #que es equivalente a w=w+1
    elif ((lista[0] == 'Z') and (int(lista[1])>int(lista[2]))):
        z += 1

if w<z:
    print("Whynot inhabitants are safer at driving than Zzyzx ones")
elif w>z:
    print("Zzyzx inhabitants are safer at driving than Whynot ones")
```

Con esos datos en resultado sería:

```
Whynot inhabitants are safer at driving than Zzyzx ones
```

Comment: muchas gracias, pero ahora me da este error:AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'                         Siento ser pesado, pero soy principiante y me gustaria saber como solucionarlo en caso de que me pasara en veces futuras

Comment: ALVARO, ¿podrías especificar que tipo de dato es la variable input, o al menos, como la obtienes?